# Plotting several contour plots on a cube using Mayavi

Tags: python, plot, contour, cube, mayavi

I'm trying to plot contours on each faces of a cube using **Mayavi**. More precisely, I want to take each cube face individually and plot a contour plot over it the same way one would proceed using Matplotlib.

The picture below can help you to get an idea of what I'm trying to do. Except in this case the cube is flattened.
[image: Contour plot over the flattened cube]

The question **is what Mayavi function should I use ? and how could I generate a suitable cube ?**

I've been through contour_surf(), surf() and mesh() but I have the feeling that none of these functions could help me to display/build a cube on which I can plot contours over its faces.

Or maybe the use of a **different library would be more relevant ?**

I had a try with Matplotlib with the code below. The rendenring is not as good as I expect it to be with Mayavi, when manipulating it's hard to distinguish which face is on the foreground.

Above all, I don't know how to get mouse coordinates when I click on a specific cube face. Indeed ultimately what I want to achieve is to drag and drop an object on a random cube face and get coordinates (x,y) and contour value z.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
from itertools import permutations

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# data to plot cube edges
a = np.linspace(0,1,10)
b = np.zeros_like(a)
c = np.zeros_like(a)
c.fill(1)

# draw wire cube to help visualization
for i in permutations((a,b,b),3):  

    ax.plot(i[0],i[1],i[2], 'k--', linewidth=2)

for i in permutations((a,c,c),3):  

    ax.plot(i[0],i[1],i[2], 'k--', linewidth=2)

for i in permutations((a,c,b),3):  

    ax.plot(i[0],i[1],i[2], 'k--', linewidth=2)

# Making the grid and data for contours
X,Y = np.mgrid[0:1:10j, 0:1:10j]
Z = np.random.randint(5, size=X.shape)

# Plotting contours, here the trick is to swap (X,Y,Z) out to prevent 
# projection
ax.contourf(X,Y,Z, zdir='z', offset=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.contourf(Y,Z,X, zdir='y', offset=0, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.contourf(Z,Y,X, zdir='x', offset=0, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.contourf(Y,Z,X, zdir='y', offset=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.contourf(Z,Y,X, zdir='x', offset=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

# Setting axis limits and labels
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim(0, 1)
ax.set_axis_off()

# get a proper view 
ax.view_init(elev=-22., azim=-135)
plt.show()
```

[Result using matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN5Cl.png)

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I've re-edited the post, should be clearer now.